# Tensorflow Lite model outputs greater values than Tensorflow model

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I've trained a model in Tensorflow so the max output value that can produce is 1.0. Then I converted it to Tensorflow Lite to put on android and now the Tensorflow Lite model produce values much greater than 1.0. What can I do to fix this?

I am using Tensorflow 2.5

tf model -> tflite model script

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("/content/drive/MyDrive/savedmodel")
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
ite_models_dir = pathlib.Path("/content/drive/MyDrive/tflite_models/")
tflite_models_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)

tflite_model_quant_file = tflite_models_dir/"model_temp_quant.tflite"
tflite_model_quant_file.write_bytes(tflite_quant_model)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In my Tensorflow model I had some operations that could not convert to Tensorflow Lite model. Here is a guide about operation conversion https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_compatibility. I changed them now everything converts right.

Answer (score 0):

You should show more detail about how you convert the model, maybe your preprocess and post process. Wrong output may come from them.

Comment: Please try the conversion without quantization. Not all the models is working well with the quantization.